# How to debug crash involving only Android framework code?

Tags: android, android-debug

Occasionally I get crash reports (in Firebase) where the stacktrace includes only Framework code. For example:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0
android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange (SpannableStringBuilder.java:1270)
android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan (SpannableStringBuilder.java:684)
android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan (SpannableStringBuilder.java:677)
android.text.Selection.setSelection (Selection.java:76)
android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.onTouchEvent (ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:284)
arrow_right
android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent (TextView.java:10140)
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent (View.java:10920)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2842)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2527)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2842)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2527)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2842)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2527)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2842)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2527)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2842)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2527)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2842)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2527)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2842)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2527)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2842)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2527)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2842)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2527)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2842)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2527)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2842)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2527)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:623)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1909)
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent (Activity.java:3247)
android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent (SourceFile:68)
android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent (SourceFile:68)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:585)
android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:11149)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5227)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:5076)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4580)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4633)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4599)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4736)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4793)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4580)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4633)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4599)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4580)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7210)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:7142)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7103)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7321)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent (InputEventReceiver.java:185)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents (InputEventReceiver.java)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents (InputEventReceiver.java:176)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput (ViewRootImpl.java:7284)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7348)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:930)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:705)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:634)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:916)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6816)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1563)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Since there is no element from my code, I cannot catch such an exception and cannot grab any useful information to log.  In this particular example, there seems to be no way to find out which TextView in my code this responds to.

The only thing I can think of is to replace every TextView with a custom TextView (and so override `onTouchEvent()` to catch and report the exception), but there are a lot of TextViews so is there another way?

Note: I cannot reproduce this problem on my own devices.

Comment: same issue for me also

Comment: by any chance, did you able to fix it? thanks in advance